# MarkLogic construct query use cts:element-query

Tags: marklogic

I have a query with sample XML below:

```
<doc>
  <sample>
    <key>key</key>
  </sample>
  <sample>
    <key>key</key>
    <key>key</key>
  </sample>
  <sample>
    <key>key</key>
  </sample>
</doc>
```

This is a xml and I don't want get it when search with this query:

```
cts:search(fn:doc(),cts:element-query("sample",cts:word-query("key",(("min-occurs=3"))))
```

I have make a restricted condition. I want to get the doc what tag in sample tag occurred rather than 3 times. But I can get up XML, because `cts:element-query("sample")` get this

```
<doc>
  <sample>
    <key>key</key>
  </sample>
  <sample>
    <key>key</key>
    <key>key</key>
  </sample>
  <sample>
    <key>key</key>
  </sample>
</doc>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I am not clear as to exactly what you want to find or exclude. Are you looking to search for docs that may have a `sample` element and only return the documents that have a `sample` with *at least* 3 `key` values in any one `sample` element?

Comment: yes.I want get a document that a single sample element within 3 keys element.Not is a document within 3 keys element.It looks like invalid in this element query in <sample>

Answer (score 0):

The query that you posted has two issues. 1. The first parameter for cts:element-query() is supposed to be a QName, but it is just the string value "sample". It should be `xs:QName("sample")` 2. You are missing a trailing parenthesis

When I run:

```
cts:search(fn:doc(),cts:element-query(xs:QName("sample"),cts:word-query("key",(("min-occurs=3")))))
```

with some dummy docs inserted, one of which does have 3 `<key>key</key>` inside of a `sample` element, and one that does, it only returns the one document that does have a `sample` element with 3 `key` elements, but it is because `cts:search()` will run `filtered` by default, so it is eliminating the docs returned from the index-resolved candidates.

If you aren't sure what element under `sample` will have the `key` value, then you could enable:

> **word positions**
> Index word positions for faster phrase and near searches (slower document loads and larger database files).

With **word positions** enabled, I am getting accurate unfiltered results.

```
cts:search(fn:doc(),
      cts:element-query(xs:QName("sample"), cts:word-query("key","min-occurs=3")), 
      "unfiltered")
```

Comment: Hi Hansen.We have saw my datebase setting.fast element word searches,element word positions,fast element phrase searches,
element value positions is true.But I also get that document within 3 key but not  within a single sample element.Can you tell me how do you setting about marklogic database?

Comment: Sorry. Element <Key> is a sample .I don't know Which element in <sample>. I must need word-query to search . Earlier you said you could use option filtered.Can you show me your query plan. I don't know how to use query plan check whether the result is filtered

Comment: You can use the function https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:plan to see the query plan.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!I have resolved use "filtered"